# How to monitor signal in SystemVerilog program block

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to learn few things about testbenches with SystemVerilog.
However I couldn't seem to find a way to monitor DUT signal inside program block

Consider following example.
Signal 'dummy' is output of DUT and input to program block.
Now I need to monitor 'dummy' in program block to raise a flag 'test' when 'dummy' has particular value.

In general module-driven testbench, I would simply write always @(dummy), but always blocks are not allowed under program. How would I achieve this?

Comment: I remember that someone said the program block has some issue and do not really suggest to use it.

Comment: @EnchanterThunderbird can you state some references about this issues?

Comment: See http://go.mentor.com/programblocks for recommendations on avoiding program blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write sequential code like this:

```
program test(input dummy);
  initial begin
    ...
    wait(dummy == <something>);
    ...
    @(posedge dummy);
    ...    
  end
endprogram
```

Or you could emulate an `always` construct using a `forever` loop.

```
program test(input dummy);
  initial begin
    forever begin
      @(posedge dummy);
      if (dummy == <something>) ...
    end 
  end
endprogram
```

Comment: awesome I can add wait under fork-join so TB can work properly through general execution as well as I can check the signal required